# My $(document).ready(function() work in local but not on Cloud9

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a series of $(document).ready(function() which only works in local. And I don't understand why. Here is an example. Thanks very much for your help.

```
<a href="#"><img src=images/folder_icon.png id="folder1"></a>
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-block">
    <span class="modal-close">X</span>
    <span class="modal-window">W</span>
    <span class="modal-trait">_</span>
    <div class="modal-header">Projects</div>
      <img src="images/folder_icon.png" class="image-folder">
      <img src="images/folder_icon.png" class="image-folder">
      <img src="images/folder_icon.png" class="image-folder">
  </div>
</div>


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#folder1").click(function(){
      $(".modal").show(0);
    });
    $(".modal-close").click(function(){
      $(".modal").hide(0);
    });
```

Comment: What does your debugging console show you? Is jQuery loading properly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Is everything loaded, see the Network tab in the Dev Tools.

Comment: Clarify for me, by Cloud9: you mean the co-coding software `http://c9.io`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
(function(){
     $("#folder1").click(function(){
      $(".modal").show(0);
    });
    $(".modal-close").click(function(){
      $(".modal").hide(0);
    });
}());
```

or like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#folder1").click(function () {
        $(".modal").show(0);
    });
    $(".modal-close").click(function () {
        $(".modal").hide(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: Won't change anything. You're still using $ which the C9 IDE can't identify through external libraries. (downvoted).

Answer (score 0):

Add `/*global $*/` in the your JavaScript on top of everything, it's the c9 IDE that mixes it up with `<script(s)>` and external links.

Comment: Hover the C9 IDE red circle error and see what it tells you to add.

Comment: If I add /*global $*/ the errors disappear but the scripts still don't work. If I take it out I keep having the same error "$ is not defined".

Comment: Make sure that you've actually included the JQuery library. C9 does not affect your code what-so-ever with library checking. This is a manual task.

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks very much @Luicy it was that. Stupid spelling mistakes which I would have never found out. Argh